# URL Query params in AMP HTML canonical <link tag

Tags: amp-html

I am attempting to use URL query params in the `<link rel="canonical"` tag in an `AMP HTML` page.

So far the only solution I have found is to switch to `server side rendering--` but I would like to continue to use `amp-mustache` with static pages if possible.

Is there any way to dynamically generate the canonical link tag or include URL query params in it while still maintaining valid `AMP HTML`?

Comment: you can not use amp-mustache in head, it is body tag.

Answer (score 0):

It not possible technically because amp-mustache or amp-select or any other amp tag which handle dynamic data, will not work in head tag. And if you look this logically(if we are looking this on a single AMP page),we are trying to map one AMP page to multiple canonical page, which is not possible. You can have a one to one mapping between AMP and canonical, however if you only have an AMP page that is fine, but you can not map one AMP to multiple canonical pages.

So when you create these AMP pages, you can set the parameters according to your requirements. After that you can not make any changes in this canonical URL.